# The accept() function in the server doesn't seem to accept new connection from the client

Tags: c, sockets, networking, unix-socket

I was trying the code from *UNIX Network Programming*, the socket networking API 
Where I encountered a the code for a simple server client and server based example

the code for server is

```
#define BL 10

void *get_in_addr(struct sockaddr *sa)
{
  if (sa->sa_family == AF_INET)
  {
    return &(((struct sockaddr_in*) sa)->sin_addr);
  }
  return &(((struct sockaddr_in6*) sa)->sin6_addr);
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
  struct sockaddr_in server, client;
  int listenfd;
  int port;

  if (argc < 2)
  {
    printf("Port Not specified Error ~~ ! ");
    exit(0);
  }

  port = atoi(argv[1]);
  memset(&server, 0, sizeof(server));
  server.sin_family = AF_INET;
  server.sin_addr.s_addr = htons(INADDR_ANY);
  server.sin_port = htons(port);

  listenfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

  if (bind(listenfd, (struct sockaddr *) &server, sizeof(server)) == 0)
    printf("\n [~] Bind Sucessfull \n");

  if (listen(listenfd, BL) == 0)
    printf("\n [~] Listenig on port %d \n\n ", port);

  while (1)
  {
    socklen_t clientlen = sizeof(client);
    printf("%d", clientlen);
    int conffd = accept(listenfd, (struct sockaddr *) &client, &clientlen);
    char s[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];
    inet_ntop(AF_INET, get_in_addr((struct sockaddr *) &client), s, sizeof(s));
    if (conffd == -1)
      printf("\n not Accepted \n");
    else
    {
      printf("Got a connection from %s", s);
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

and then the code for the client is

```
int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{

  struct sockaddr_in server;
  int listenfd;
  int port = 11111;
  memset(&server, 0, sizeof(server));
  inet_pton(AF_INET, argv[1], &server.sin_addr);
  server.sin_family = AF_INET;
  server.sin_port = htons(port);

  listenfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
  if (connect(listenfd, (struct sockaddr *) &server, sizeof(server)) != 0)
  {
    printf("Connection error ! \n");
  }

  return 0;
}
```

The problem here is when I start the server and run the client , nothing happens in the server  but its supposed to say " got  a connection from  #IP "

the output is :

```
./server 11111

[~] Bind Sucessfull 

[~] Listenig on port 11111
```

the should have been output :

```
./server 11111

[~] Bind Sucessfull 

[~] Listenig on port 11111 

Got an connection from 127.0.0.1
```

So I thought there was some thing wrong with the client ,

so I checked it , I closed the server and ran the client again now it said connection error

which means that the client is working fine , so the problem was with server's accept()

I can't seem to find  whats causing the problem .

If anyone could explain whats wrong would be really helpfull :)

Comment: Have you tried just printing something direct after the `accept()` call in your server?

Comment: Cyclone yeah nothing gets printed , that because accept is waiting for a new connection

Comment: Have you tried passing `PF_INET` instead of `AF_INET` in your call to `socket()` in the server? I'm thinking `AF` adress family, while `PF` protocol family. Not sure if that will solve anything though.

Comment: Yeah still nothing :/

Comment: What platform are you on? I'm thinking that this could be some kind of firewall issue e.g the client isn't allowed to connect on the specific port?

Comment: I think I spotted the problem, you need to bind the client to an address before trying to connect to the server. In other words call `socket()`, `bind()` and finally `connect()`

Comment: @Cyclone: Binding the client is not necessary. The OS decides which IP-interface to use.

Comment: @alk - is this always the case? Didn't know that, but reading up on it now. I'm used to bind to a specific adress before trying to connect.

Comment: This `char s[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];` shall be `char s[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN + 1];`

Comment: Listening socketd need to be bound to where they shall listen on, connecting sockets do not need to care. One however **may** also bind connecting sockets. Also this shall be clear from the example sources the OP found in the UNP book.

Comment: @alk  no changing the size of s didnt change anything 
why do u think that changing the size matters ? 
the thing is its not getting past the accept() ;

Comment: You are correct the size of `s` would not help if `accept()` blocks, it would  however help essentially, if you solved this issue. Read on C-"strings"'s 0-termination, why.

Comment: Also you might like to add to the question the `#include` statements you use in your "*real*" code.

Comment: Well, probably a stupid remark. Try to put newlines at the end of your `printf` strings, or call `fflush(stdout)` after `printf`.

Comment: As Marian's finding will solve your issue, take two advices: 1. Always log unbuffered, that is log to `stderr`. 2. Follow the opposite logging strategy from what you do now, do not log success, but do log any possible kind of failure. This is called the "No News Is Good News" communication policy.

Comment: @Marian man u were right :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a follow up of the comments above, you should know that the standard output `stdout` is *line buffered*, which means, it will send the contents of the buffer to the output screen only upon encountering a newline `\n`. So until and unless your print string is having a newline [or you're flushing the buffer manually, using `fflush(stdout)`], the content of the buffer will not be flushed to the screen.

In your code, upon a successful `accept()`, `printf()` is called and the string supplied with `printf()` is send to the buffer related with `stdout`, but the content is not *flushed* to the screen. The control will continue and it will be in *blocked* state in next `accept()` call. So, your output buffer is not getting a chance to be flushed to the screen in your case.

Please add a newline character [\n] in your print string. It will cause the content of the buffer to be flushed immediately and you'll be able to see the output on screen.

```
 printf("Got a connection from %s\n", s);
```

---

<sup>SideNote: *[Just for checking the presence of the content in your output buffer]* As we know, the program termination will cause all the associated buffers to be flushed, you can try terminating the server execution manually, [maybe by pressing crtl+c] and you'll be able to see the print statement on your screen</sup>

Answer (score -1):

Change the line given below in server code

```
server.sin_addr.s_addr = htons(INADDR_ANY);
```

to

```
server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
```

Comment: This most likley won't change anything, as `INADDR_ANY` propably is defined as `0`.